# How can I return a response to an AngularJS $http POST to Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, heroku, sinatra

I am able to successfully POST from AngularJS to my Sinatra route such that I get a "200" Status.

When I inspect in Chrome, I see the request payload as follows:

```
{"input":"testing"}
```

But response is empty.

Here is how I am POST-ing:

```
        $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://floating-beyond-3787.herokuapp.com/angular",
        /*url: "https://worker-aws-us-east-1.iron.io/2/projects/542c8609827e3f0005000123/tasks/webhook?code_name=botweb&oauth=LOo5Nc0x0e2GJ838_nbKoheXqM0",*/
        data: {input: $scope.newChat}
    })

    .success(function (data)
    {
     // $scope.chats.push(data);
        $scope.chats.push($scope.newChat)
     // if successful then get the value from the cache? 

    })
    .error(function (data)
    {
      $scope.errors.push(data);
    });

  };

  $scope.newChat = null
```

Chrome under Request Payload shows it properly -- as above.

When I check the logs in Heroku where I run my Sinatra app, I can't tell if I am properly processing the request payload.  And I'm definitely not getting anything in the Response:

```
post '/angular' do
  puts "params: #{params}"
  puts params[:input]
  puts @json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

   return RestClient.post 'https://worker.io' {:send => params[:input]}

end
```

My expectation is:

1. The Sinatra app can receive the payload :input
2. It can successfully post to my worker on iron.io
3. It can return something back in the Response to Angular JS along with Success.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you are running into a case where the request.body has already been read further up the chain before hitting your route.

Try the following

```
request.body.rewind
request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read
```

This is a fairly common issue encountered in Sinatra so if this addresses your issue you may want to put it in a before filter.

```
before do
  request.body.rewind
  @request_payload = JSON.parse request.body.read
end
```

Also the following will not work with a JSON payload.

```
params[:input]
```

The `params[:field]` style works if the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to allow accessing form data in a traditional web application style.  It also works to pull params off a parameterized route; something like the following.

```
post '/angular/:data'
  puts params[:data]

  # Do whatever processing you need in here
  # assume you created a no_errors var to track problems with the
  # post

  if no_errors
    body(json({key: val, key2: val2, keyetc: valetc}))
    status 200
  else 
    body(({oh_snap: "An error has occurred!"}).to_json) # json(hash) or hash.to_json should both work here.
    status 400 # Replace with your appropriate 4XX error here... 
  end
end
```

Something I did recently was to use this last style `post 'myroute/:myparam` and then Base64 encode a JSON payload on the client side and send it in the URL :myparam slot.  This is a bit of a hack and is not something I would recommend as a general practice.  I had a client application that could not properly encode the JSON data + headers into the request body; so this was a viable workaround.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I had the params[:input] in there so I could actually test if the issue was on teh client end or not.

Comment: My alternative has been to post directly to worker.io but worker responds with creating the task -- but then there's no way to issue back the response after the job is done.

Comment: Once I receive the payload, is there a way for me to then return the worker return back to the AngularJS which made the post?

Comment: To clarify; are you asking if it is possible to return a payload back when the post route finishes up?

Comment: Yes.  But only after it receives the payload from POST'ing to the external webserivce.

Comment: I've added some additional information in my answer above.  You just need to set the body and then your status code at the end of the route after you are done with processing the post request.  This is all synchronous (runs in the order it is called and blocks/waits before moving on to the next statement).

Comment: I see...let me give that a go....it was strange that when I wanted to output the payload in the Sinatra route I got nothing :(

Comment: Hmm...I am having some challenges....it is coming to the /angular route as method OPTIONS ---even though I am clearly stating it as POST

Comment: Argh --- I am getting a 500 error and the logs saying JSON parsers needs two octets, which means that it is submitting a null value....

Comment: Is this something where you can post it to a github repo? Without seeing the actual code; I'm not sure where to go on this.  The above should work; I use Sinatra almost exclusively for my web services.

Comment: Here is the sinatra:  https://github.com/angelacode/kaya-repo/blob/master/web_post.rb

Comment: Here is the angularJS script.js that performs the POST:  https://github.com/angelacode/kaya-repo/blob/master/public/js/script.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62929/discussion-between-bigtunacan-and-angela).

Comment: Thanks @bigtunacan...sorry for the delay, the chat window was closed

Comment: No problem; the chat system here on SO is a bit unique.  If you would like to follow up on email instead you can reach me at joieyseeley+so@gmail.com